# Django: Определение города

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ip, геолокация

Стоит задача в определении города человека, зашедшого на сайт. Понимаю, что у многих vpn, но всё же.

Когда-то я это реализовывал через `GeoIp`. Но, как я понял, эта либа не русифицирована.

Что можете посоветовать для реализации данной задачи. Должно быть русифицировано. И более-менее нормальная база для стран постсоветского пространства (особенно Казахстан).

Comment: Как насчёт dadata.ru?

Comment: Не слышал о таком. Он бесплатный? Есть примеры его подключения в джанго?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте настроить nginx https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html

Дальше можно будет в заголовках получать город и обрабатывать в какой-нибудь middleware